# Attempting to use a Datetime from a mouseevent from Matplotlib within Tkinter

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, tkinter, mouseevent

I have a plot of data  (using `matplotlib` and `Tkinter`) and created a funtion that responds to the user clicking on a point on the plot. I got the program to return the correct y value (because it's simply a float type). However, my x-axis has `datetime` type data and when I ask it to print the x value, it prints a `numpy.float64` type. I'm looking to use the datetime value the user chooses, but I need to access it first.

One example of the x-value returned: 735764.731698

Below is the function dealing with the onpick event.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from images_to_list import images_to_list
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def onpick(self,event):    

      im=Image.open('C:\Carbonite\EL_36604.02_231694\EL_36604.02_231694_2015-06-15 10.39.57.jpeg')
        im.show()

        x = event.mouseevent.xdata
        y = event.mouseevent.ydata
        x1 = event.mouseevent.x
        y1 = event.mouseevent.y

        dataind = event.ind[0]

        print type(x),x,y,x1,y1, len(event.ind)      

        return True


#Action Creating the UI and running the program
app = App(extra)
app.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', app.onpick)
extra.mainloop()
```

Below is an example of an output when a point is chosen:

```
%run "C:\Carbonite\Main_interface_file.py"
<type 'numpy.float64'> 735764.732134 1.93689320388 499 242.0 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally mpl converts dates -> floats (which it knows how to plot) and converts back to date-time for labeling the axes.  The function you need here is [`num2date`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date)

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdate
dt = mdate.num2date(num)
```

ex

```
In [222]:  mdate.num2date(735764.732134).isoformat()
Out[222]: '2015-06-15T17:34:16.377604+00:00'
```

Also note that the float representation mpl uses internally is float days from 0001-01-01